# How to create synchronized timers in EJB 3?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0

I am using timers in EJB 3. I have the below requirements to accomplish.

Ex: Assume I have created a timer with expiry interval for 10mins, the initial timer started and it is performing some task which is taking more time (say 15mins). Meanwhile the server will start another timer with the same name and the expiry time has been reached. I want to restrict the server to start another timer if existing timer is still running.

Also I want to stop all timers but when I use `timer.getInfo()` and get the name of timer, the application hangs.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You should post some code. That will significantly help people help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have created seems like a interval-timer/scheduler which keeps executing after a certain interval, irrespective of previous actions.

Try creating the timer manually, create it in a bean marked as @Startup initializing with the application startup, can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055602/366964) further.

```
//---

     @Timeout
     public void execute(Timer timer){

       /*
          -- Time consuming computation
       */

        createTimer(sec, min, hour)
     }

//---
```

Therefore, once its created at the application startup, it will be creating a chain of timers. So even if your task takes more time than usual, the next will be created only after the completion/expiry of the previous timer.